# Python cant list files in a directory

Tags: python-3.x

I follow some articles regarding on how to list files in a directory using the below code :

```
import os, sys

path = "/python 3.6.4"
dirs = os.list(path)

for file in dirs:
    print file
```

Note: The .py file in which the above code is on the same directory as the path.
Im running it using a command prompt. Any idea would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Drop the `/`. Just `python 3.6.4`. It's cleaner.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory I think you can refer answer 218 in above link.